# Main.go won't run after correct build

Tags: git, go, backend, go-fiber

I started learning go and made a crm app, just to find that after building main, it won't run.

This is the error shown in the terminal:

```
PS crm-go-fiber> go build .\main.go
PS crm-go-fiber> go run .\main.exe
main module (github.com/Lo0mi3x/crm-go-fiber) does not contain package github.com/Lo0mi3x/crm-go-fiber/main.exe
```

I'm new at programming, GitHub, and stuff but I did my commit & push, and everything correct.
Even clone the code from my repository and tried it again, but no changes.

Comment: Please stop using file name arguments to go run and go build. Please read and follow the tutorials on go.dev/doc. You _build_ your program by running `go build` (nothing else) and run the generated program via `./crm-go-fiber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing your program incorrectly.

```bash
go build .\main.go
```

This command compiles and builds `main.go`.  However, you should generally not pass filenames to `go build`. The better approach is simply `go build`.  But that's not your actual problem here...

```bash
go run .\main.exe
```

This command attempts to build and run a package called `main.exe` located in the current directory.  The error message you see:

```
main module (github.com/Lo0mi3x/crm-go-fiber) does not contain package github.com/Lo0mi3x/crm-go-fiber/main.exe
```

Is telling you that it cannot find a package caleld `main.exe` within your current package.

If you wish to execute the program you compiled in the first command, just execute it as normal:

```bash
.\main.exe
```